# Docker and php "standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error". Also entrypoint fails to read parameters for exec

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

ARG USERID=1000
ARG GROUPID=1000

ENV DOCKER_UID=${USERID} \
    DOCKER_GID=${GROUPID} \
    PHP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d" \
    XDEBUG_CONF_FILE=${PHP_CONF_DIR}/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    XDEBUG_HOST="" \
    XDEBUG_IDE_KEY="" \
    XDEBUG_PORT=9000 \
    XDEBUG_DBGP=FALSE



RUN echo "Installing Development Dpendencies \n" &&\
    echo http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc wget autoconf &&\
    apk add --update bash shadow git bash-completion bash-doc &&\
    echo "Installing composer \n" &&\
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', '/tmp/composer-setup.php');" &&\
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" &&\
    php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer &&\
    rm -rf /tmp/cpmposer-setup.php &&\
    chmod +x /bin/composer &&\
    echo "Installing xdebug" &&\
    pecl install xdebug  &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug &&\
    echo "Configuring Xdebug \n" &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_mode=req" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    cp ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}.orig &&\
    echo "Making a Development User \n" &&\
    addgroup -g ${DOCKER_GID} developer &&\
    mkdir -p /home/developer/code &&\
    adduser -D -u ${DOCKER_UID} -G developer -h /home/developer -s /bin/bash developer &&\
    chown developer:developer -R /home/developer/code &&\
    apk del build-dependencies &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# I make seperate layer because Entrypoint is most likely to change
COPY ./entrypoint/develop_entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN echo "Fixing Permissions on Entrypoint Script \n" &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    echo "Fixing Permissions on Entrypoint Script \n" &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

VOLUME /home/developer/code
WORKDIR /home/developer/code

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

And I use the following `docker-compose.yml` to launch it:

```
version: '3'
services:
  develop:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile_base
    image: myapp/php:dev-n-build
    volumes:
       - ${CODE_BASE_PATH}:/home/developer/code

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 7080:7080
    links:
      - develop
    volumes:
      - ${CODE_BASE_PATH}:/home/developer/code
```

But for Some reason I receve the following error:

```
Creating network "dist_default" with the default driver
Creating dist_develop_1 ... done
Creating dist_nginx_1   ... done
Attaching to dist_develop_1, dist_nginx_1
develop_1  | standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"
dist_develop_1 exited with code 1
```

My docker version is:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77
```

And the `docker-compose` version is:

```
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa5906
```

Also my `entrypoint.sh` us the following:

```
#/bin/sh

USER_ID=$(id -u developer)
GROUP_ID=$(id -g developer)

echo "Setting the correct user and group id for shell use"
if [ ${DOCKER_UID} != ${USER_ID} ]; then
  usermod -u ${DOCKER_UID} developer
fi

if [ ${DOCKER_GID} != ${GROUP_ID} ]; then
  groupmod -g ${DOCKER_GID} developer
fi

echo "Setup xdebug"
cp ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}.orig ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}

if [ -z ${XDEBUG_HOST} ]; then
    ip=$(netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10)
    XDEBUG_HOST=${ip}
fi

echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
echo "xdebug.repomote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}

if [ XDEBUG_DBGP = TRUE ]; then
    echo "xdebug.remote.handler=dbgp" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
fi

if [ ! -z "${XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}" ]; then
    echo "xdebug.idekey=\"${XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}\"" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
fi

echo "Launch application"
exec "$@"
```

So I wonder:

- What does the `standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "exec format error"` indicates.
- How I can fix this problem.

## Edit 1

I managed to fix it by spawning a shell into the `ENTRYPOINT` to my `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh", "php-fpm"]
```

I also fixed the typo into the Entrypoint script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

USER_ID=$(id -u developer)
GROUP_ID=$(id -g developer)

echo "Setting the correct user and group id for shell use"
if [ ${DOCKER_UID} != ${USER_ID} ]; then
  usermod -u ${DOCKER_UID} developer
fi

if [ ${DOCKER_GID} != ${GROUP_ID} ]; then
  groupmod -g ${DOCKER_GID} developer
fi

echo "Setup xdebug"
cp ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}.orig ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}

if [ -z ${XDEBUG_HOST} ]; then
    ip=$(netstat -rn | grep "^0.0.0.0 " | cut -d " " -f10)
    XDEBUG_HOST=${ip}
fi

echo "xdebug.remote_host=${XDEBUG_HOST}" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
echo "xdebug.repomote_port=${XDEBUG_PORT}" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}

if [ XDEBUG_DBGP = TRUE ]; then
    echo "xdebug.remote.handler=dbgp" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
fi

if [ ! -z "${XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}" ]; then
    echo "xdebug.idekey=\"${XDEBUG_IDE_KEY}\"" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}
fi

echo "Launch application"
exec "$@"
```

But for some awkward reason the `php-fpm` is not launched. Do you have Any idea why?

If I change the last line om my `entrypoint.sh` from:

```
exec "$@"
```

Into

```
echo "Params $@"

exec "$@"
```

I get the following output:

```
develop_1  | Setting the correct user and group id for shell use
develop_1  | Setup xdebug
develop_1  | Launch application
develop_1  | Params 
nginx_1    | 2019/06/14 14:00:04 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "develop" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32
nginx_1    | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "develop" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:32
php-docker_base_1 exited with code 0
php-docker_develop_1 exited with code 0
php-docker_nginx_1 exited with code 1
```

Older attempts such as this one: https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/blob/master/dockerfiles/fpm_alpine/Dockerfile_mysql seeld to work having entrypoint loke that: https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/blob/master/scripts/entrypoint.sh

Did something changed into Docker and way that entrypoints are being handled?

Also even by doing:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh","-c","/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh", "php-fpm"]
```

Does not work either.

Comment: Which version of Docker are you using, which operating system and what CPU architecture?

Comment: could you show what is inside of `/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh`?

Comment: I updated the quiestion for the version.

Comment: I also added to the question my entrypoint as well. the `/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh` is the same of my entrypoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to switch from exec format into shell format in order to launch your entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh php-fpm
```

Also remove the last CMD from it as you can see the `ENTRYPOINT` will retreive **DIRECTLY** the required parameters. In your case is to pass which command to execute, that is the `php-fpm`.

Also as you can see fix the typo as @Ntwobike points out.

As a Result the `Dockerfile` will be:

```
FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine

ARG USERID=1000
ARG GROUPID=1000

ENV DOCKER_UID=${USERID} \
    DOCKER_GID=${GROUPID} \
    PHP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d" \
    XDEBUG_CONF_FILE=${PHP_CONF_DIR}/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini \
    XDEBUG_HOST="" \
    XDEBUG_IDE_KEY="" \
    XDEBUG_PORT=9000 \
    XDEBUG_DBGP=FALSE



RUN echo "Installing Development Dpendencies \n" &&\
    echo http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories &&\
    apk add --update --virtual build-dependencies build-base gcc wget autoconf &&\
    apk add --update bash shadow git bash-completion bash-doc &&\
    echo "Installing composer \n" &&\
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', '/tmp/composer-setup.php');" &&\
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', '/tmp/composer-setup.php') === '48e3236262b34d30969dca3c37281b3b4bbe3221bda826ac6a9a62d6444cdb0dcd0615698a5cbe587c3f0fe57a54d8f5') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;" &&\
    php /tmp/composer-setup.php --install-dir=/bin --filename=composer &&\
    rm -rf /tmp/cpmposer-setup.php &&\
    chmod +x /bin/composer &&\
    echo "Installing xdebug" &&\
    pecl install xdebug  &&\
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug &&\
    echo "Configuring Xdebug \n" &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.max_nesting_level = 1000" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_mode=req" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    echo "xdebug.remote_log=xdebug.log" >> ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} &&\
    cp ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE} ${XDEBUG_CONF_FILE}.orig &&\
    echo "Making a Development User \n" &&\
    addgroup -g ${DOCKER_GID} developer &&\
    mkdir -p /home/developer/code &&\
    adduser -D -u ${DOCKER_UID} -G developer -h /home/developer -s /bin/bash developer &&\
    chown developer:developer -R /home/developer/code &&\
    apk del build-dependencies &&\
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

# I make seperate layer because Entrypoint is most likely to change
COPY ./entrypoint/develop_entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN echo "Fixing Permissions on Entrypoint Script \n" &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    echo "Fixing Permissions on Entrypoint Script \n" &&\
    chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh &&\
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

VOLUME /home/developer/code
WORKDIR /home/developer/code

ENTRYPOINT /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh php-fpm
```

And focus solving the rest 98 problems (you had 99 ;) ).

**PS** Still IDK why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your `entrypoint.sh`

```
#/bin/sh => #!/bin/sh
```

Comment: I fixed the typo still problem occurs.

Comment: were you able to build the image? what command you are running here?

Comment: I am able to build the image but I cannot launch the entrypoint.